# How to display uploaded file name in magento admin form?

Tags: magento

How can i display uploaded file name or link after successfully uploaded file at magento custom module form.I had attached screenshot for clear understanding.Please help[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to do this, you need a custom renderer for the `file` input in your form.
For this create the following class:

```
<?php
class {{Namespace}}_{{Module}}_Block_Adminhtml_{{Entity}}_Helper_File extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract{
    public function __construct($data){
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->setType('file');
    }
    public function getElementHtml(){
        $html = '';
        $this->addClass('input-file');
        $html.= parent::getElementHtml();
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->_getUrl();
            if( !preg_match("/^http\:\/\/|https\:\/\//", $url) ) {
                $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'{{entity}}'.'/'.'file' . $url; //replace this with the path to the file if you upload it somewhere else
            }
            $html .= '<br /><a href="'.$url.'">'.$this->_getUrl().'</a> ';
        }
        $html.= $this->_getDeleteCheckbox();
        return $html;
    }
    protected function _getDeleteCheckbox(){
        $html = '';
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $label = Mage::helper('{{module}}')->__('Delete File');
            $html .= '<span class="delete-image">';
            $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="'.parent::getName().'[delete]" value="1" class="checkbox" id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_delete"'.($this->getDisabled() ? ' disabled="disabled"': '').'/>';
            $html .= '<label for="'.$this->getHtmlId().'_delete"'.($this->getDisabled() ? ' class="disabled"' : '').'> '.$label.'</label>';
            $html .= $this->_getHiddenInput();
            $html .= '</span>';
        }       
        return $html;
    }
    protected function _getHiddenInput(){
        return '<input type="hidden" name="'.parent::getName().'[value]" value="'.$this->getValue().'" />';
    }
    protected function _getUrl(){
        return $this->getValue();
    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->getData('name');
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell your for to use this for the file inputs. So in your edit form tab, add this right after defining the fiedlset:

```
$fieldset->addType('file', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('{{module}}/adminhtml_{{entity}}_helper_file'));
```

Replace `{{Namespace}}`, {{Module}} and `{{Entity}}` with the appropriate values keeping the case.
`Namespace` is the namespace of your module (D'uh), `Module` is the name of your module (D'uh again), and Entity is what you are managing. Can be `Article`, `News`, `Files`....
**[EDIT]**
You can build your module using [this module creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html). It takes care of these kind of issues.
Note: I hope this is not considered self promotion. The extension is free and I get no financial benefits out of it.

Comment: Thanks @Marius for your replay.I have done same like describe above.

Comment: Hi Marius, i have added this code $fieldset->addType('file', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('homevideo/adminhtml_videos_edit_renderer_videodelete'));  in my edit form file, and the videodelete.php in that place also , but nothing is happening.

Comment: @senthil. A lot of things can be wrong. I cannot debug without having the code.

Comment: @Marius, finally i got the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found answer myself...

just create one file and extended it with magento core abstract class that is `Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Modulename_Helper_File extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract`

and added below code to admin form

```
 $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('Module_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('Module')->__('Video information')));
        $fieldset->addType('file', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('Module/adminhtml_Module_helper_file'));   /* line added  */
```